# xcode > reorganise Mutable array values

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am new to Xcode and i have created a NSmutableArray that retrieves its values from a function. i would like to able to re organise the contents of my Array

When i output my array, i get the following results

(value A,value B,value C,value D)

I would like to re organize my array to appear a customised way so i would like it to appear in the following way

(value B,value D,value A,value C)

Any ideas on how to acheve this ?

I am using xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Sort it. How do you decide the order?

Comment: i dont decide the order, i am creating my array from a function that i call via an API

Comment: You must decide the reorganised order...

Answer (score 1):

User can see the custom order and sorted order. right?

Have a `NSMutableArray`. Organise the content and Iterate to show it in `UITableview`

When you want to show sorted content in UITableView use the below method to get the sorted array.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)mySortedArray
{
 return [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
```